# awk/sed print all the digits before matching symbol

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have input with lines like this (it's a CIGAR string from sam format but it doesn't matter now):

```
123M76N55M4S
6M7N25M
32M488N
```

And I want to extract all the N's and preceding digits:

```
76N
7N
488N
```

I've tried this command:

```
sed -r 's/^.*([0-9]+N).*$/\1/'
```

But I get in the output only the last digit. How can I obtain all the preceding digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will suffice:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+N'
```

Your sed regex fails because the `.*` is too greedy. You have to make sure you don't consume any of the digits:

```
sed -r 's/(.*[^0-9])?([0-9]+N).*/\2/'
```